# Creating NPM packages, how to document them?

Tags: node.js, documentation, package, npm, jsdoc

I'm in the process of creating a few NPM packages and I'd like to know what are the best practices to write the user documentation for them (as there's very little information, and searching for anything related with `npm package documentation` inevitably yields to the npm docs themselves).

When you publish a package, where does the registry get the front page document from?

I guess that having a nice `README.md` file is the first step for anybody that browses the github repo, but I'd like to provide a convenient way to read the compiled JsDoc too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The npm package page for a package gets the data in the table at the top from either `package.json` fields in your package (name, description, dependencies, etc) or from the npm databases themselves (download graph, last published, stars, dependents, etc). The stuff below that is just the README.md converted from markdown to HTML.

So a good `README.md` is all most packages do. If you want to build your jsdoc into HTML and publish that somewhere (perhaps just the git repo itself), I would suggest just linking to that prominently in the README and calling it good.

Answer (score 3):

I found an interesting package to make the README.md out from jsdoc:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/jsdoc-to-markdown